# WCF over SSL from non-secure page

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that I need to run over SSL, I am calling it from a webpage (using jQuery) which may or may not be a secure page.  The problem is, if I make the call from a secure webpage on my site, the call runs exactly how I would expect...however, if I make the call from a non-secure page on my site, to the secure web service (using "https://" ;) ) it returns null data (via Firebug).  Anything I'm missing? Is this even possible?

Here is the configuration of the service I'm calling (I'm more than happy to provide more stuff if needed):

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="ClientServices.Membership" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceGatewayBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehavior" bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
     binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ClientServices.Membership" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SecureBinding">
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Here is the code that calls the service:

```
$.ajax({
            url: serviceUrl,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{"review":{"Username":"' + username + '"}}',
            success: function (data) {
                $.log(data);
            },
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                $.log(b);
            },
            cache: false
        });
```

**UPDATE**

If I change the service call method to "GET" and call it directly over SSL it works fine and outputs the jSon that I would expect.  It's only inside the non-secure page where the problem persists.

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code that calls the service?  Are you getting a 200 back from your service (with null data returned) or are you getting an error back?

Comment: I added the calling code for you.  This code has no problem running in other scenarios, just when the page is not secure and it's calling the secure service.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both site and service are both at yourdomain.com, then my first thoughts would be that when on the non-secure page, your browser is not attaching the cookie it has for the site domain and so when it calls the service, it isn't authenticated.

Have you used Fiddler to look at the raw HTTP header data and more importantly, what differs in this data when on the working and not-working page?

Luke